# Setting Forecolor of UnorderedList with execCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, execcommand

I am trying to make it so when I changed the colour of an editable `<div>` tag it changes **all** the text to that colour.

When I use the line `document.execCommand('foreColor', false, 'blue');` to change the color of my text it changes the colour of everything but the bullet points in an ordered or unordered list, the bullet points just stay black.

I am using the line `document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList', false, null);` and without any CSS to interfere the bullet point stays black and won't turn blue.

Is there anything I should be doing differently?